# Unix String comparison

Tags: string, unix, hive, comparison, impala

I have two variables being populated by different means, whose values I want to compare. If you notice the echo below, both variable values are identical, yet the string comparison says "no match". What could be wrong?

**Code:**

```
IMPALA_NODE=ipaddress.goes.here  
HIVE_DBNAME="dbname"  
HIVE_TABLENAME="tablename"  
CNT_FILE=$(wc -l < /tmp/filename.csv)  
CNT_EXTTABLE=`impala-shell -k -i $IMPALA_NODE -d $HIVE_DBNAME -q "select count(*)+1 from ${HIVE_TABLENAME};" --quiet -B -c`  
echo "_${CNT_FILE}_"  
echo "_${CNT_EXTTABLE}_"  
if [ "$CNT_EXTTABLE" = "20" ]; then  
echo "match"  
else  
echo "no match"  
fi
```

**Ouput:**
`_20_`
`_20_`
no match

Comment: The switch between `CNT_FILE=$(…)` and back-ticks ``CNT_EXTTABLE=`…` `` is intriguing; consistency is good and `$(…)` is generally better than the alternative. Why is your comparison against a constant 20 and not `$CNT_FILE`? Have you run the output through `od -c` or a hex dump? (`echo "$CNT_EXTTABLE XX $CNT_FILE" | od -c`) Does that show any unexpected characters? If you're not sure why two strings aren't equal, one of the first things to do is to get a byte-level representation of the strings so that you can see what it is you are comparing. Is the output from `impala-shell` coloured?

Comment: My original requirenent is to compare those two variables but since I kept getting mismatch I wanted to test if the variable compares to a constant 20 since that's what it showed in the previous echo stmt. But strangely it showed no match even when compared to constant. As I posted in the answer, it seems impala-shell is causing some kind of control character in the command output hence the no match. I don't know why echo stmt didn't show the control character though and shows just 20.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that imapala-shell puts some kind of control character in the line, so the alternative is to output the result to a file and then read it. See this link:
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/impala-user/_pSQtqPPke0

Answer (score 0):

You might try "==" in the comparison.
I would also add the 'fi' at the end of the if statement.

```
CNT_FILE=20
CNT_EXTTABLE=20

echo "_${CNT_FILE}_"
echo "_${CNT_EXTTABLE}_"

if [ "$CNT_FILE" == "$CNT_EXTTABLE" ]; then
   echo "match"
else
   echo "no match"
fi
```

%>source test.sh

```
_20_
_20_
match
```

Comment: fi was my bad pasting the code here.

== did not work either.
The variable $CNT_EXTTABLE seems to be the culprit, it is being populated by impala-shell command to retrieve record count from a table. Here is what I also noticed:

Code:
echo "${CNT_EXTTABLE//[!0-9]/}"

Ouput:
103420

I expected 20 because that is what I see in the table, not sure where that 1034 is getting prefixed from.

Comment: The code you have works as far as I can tell.   Your variable don't have the values you think.

Comment: I am really stumped, here is the entire code and output:

Code:

IMPALA_NODE=ipaddress.goes.here
HIVE_DBNAME="dbname"
HIVE_TABLENAME="tablename"
CNT_FILE=$(wc -l < /tmp/filename.csv)
CNT_EXTTABLE=`impala-shell -k -i $IMPALA_NODE -d $HIVE_DBNAME -q "select count(*)+1 from ${HIVE_TABLENAME};" --quiet -B -c`
echo "_${CNT_FILE}_"
echo "_${CNT_EXTTABLE}_"
if [ "$CNT_EXTTABLE" = "20" ]; then
  echo "match"
else
  echo "no match"
fi

Ouput:

_20_
_20_
no match